# Instagram API - hashtag count error

Tags: php, instagram

I'm working on a script written in php that will collect the number of posts there is with a certain hashtag. I've found the correct api [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) but it doesn't seem to work for me. I go through the authentication peace and receive an acnes-token but when i try to use it I get the error message:

> {"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","code":400,"error_message":"The access_token provided is invalid."}}

This is the could of page instagram redirects the user to after authentication:

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

echo $code = $_GET["code"];

$content = get_data("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/sweden?access_token=".$code) or die("could not open stream");
echo $content;
?>
```

Tankfull for any help!

Answer (score 3):

`$_GET['code']` is **not** the access token.

You must use the code to request an access token from `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token`.

See "Step Three: Request the access_token" [in the docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

Comment: Thank you I've now received the access token http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN, but can't find a way to read it. I've only worked with ? in the url not #

Comment: @JohannesFlood You cannot process a URL fragment (i.e. anything after the `#`) with PHP. That data is not passed to the server. It sounds like you switched to `response_type=token` but that's intended for use with JavaScript. Switch it back, and do step 3 as stated in my answer.